# why do we put equal to zero when trying to solve the polynomial inequality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials

I'm taking a course on algebra, the method my instructor showed to solve polynomial inequalities, is to put factors equal to zero to get "points of interest"??

When you reach step like following
$$(x+7)(x-4)>0$$
we put each factor equal to zero and get x, put them into number line and check each part, whether that part satisfies the inequality.

But why are we putting, factors equal to zero? This is my question.

I tried asking my instructor, it didn't make any sense to me - he said something like (not verbatim, and probably not accurate)  - polynomial functions are continuous, and all polynomials will cross the x-axis, and when they do $x$ will be zero, something like this. He mentioned intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Well, what he said is the reason.  For a continuous function, the sign must be constant between zeroes.  Once you have found those zeroes, you can read off all the signs just by evaluating at one point in the interval (or by looking at the signs of the factors).

Comment: Well, that's what I want to know, I don't have any calc background, but I have knowledge of functions and relations. I'm not questioning whether the instructor was wrong or right, he most likely said something accurate, but I could not comprehend it. I was expecting someone could help me here.

Comment: What don't you understand?  To change sign, you must pass through $0$.  That statement requires proof, but it is quite intuitive, isn't it?

Comment: Word of caution:  in this case, it's easy to convince yourself that, in fact, the sign *must* change at each zero.  But this is not always true.  For the inequality $x^2(x^2-1)>0$ there are zeroes at $\{-1,0,1\}$ but the sign does not change at $0$.

Comment: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) is a link to a discussion of the Intermediate Value Theorem.  That's what you need here.  That's what says that a continuous function can only change sign at a zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every polynomial can be written as a comparison with $0$, by doing basic algebraic manipulation. Polynomials are continuous, and they don't have holes or breaks, so the value of $y$ or $f(x)$ will change smoothly, and as we are comparing with zero, as we go from the negative value of polynomial $y < 0$ towards $y\geq0$ it will surly pass through $y=0$ that is x-axis itself, and we know that $y=0$ is solution of the polynomial, and we find it by putting factors equal to zero.

Now we know that we are comparing with $y=0$ so when we move left or right of the point where $y=0$, the value of $y$ is either less or more than zero, so from here we can get the value of inequality easily.

---

An excellent comment has been maintained above that - Word of caution: in this case, it's easy to convince yourself that, in fact, the sign must change at each zero. But this is not always true. For the inequality $x^2(x^2−1)>0$ there are zeroes at $\{−1,0,1\}$ but the sign does not change at $ 0$

but obviously, it doesn't make our method incorrect, Zero tells us the sign might change, we must not take it for granted that it will change,  now checking whether it changes or not is up to us to test, and based on that can be written answer of inequality, It will surely add one more step to our process, but will not give an incorrect answer.

Furthermore, if you have read my answer I would suggest one to think, [does the sign of a rational or polynomial equation remains the same for the entire interval?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4744944/does-sign-of-a-rational-or-polynomial-equations-remains-the-same-for-entire-inte)

Answer (score 1):

The key here is that the sign of a polynomial can only change when it cross through $y=0$. It can't be positive and then suddenly be negative without crossing through $y=0$, that's what your instructor is getting at with the IVT. Try it on a graph - start above the $y$-axis, and without lifting your pencil or folding/tearing the paper you're drawing on, try to get below the $y$-axis without touching it, and you won't be able to.

So, the only places where the sign of $(x+7)(x-4)$ can change is at $x=-7$ or $x=4$.

This is where I like to think about a number line, and just slide my way across from left to right. Start by imagining that $x$ is a very large (magnitude) negative number. Then, it's pretty obvious that $x+7 < 0$ and $x-4<0$, so $(x+7)(x-4)>0$ because you have two negative factors multiplying to a positive number.

Slide your way along the number line from left to right, and the very first place that sign can change is at $x=-7$. Any $x$-value you choose left of $-7$ has to result in a positive product. Now at $x=-7$, the product will be $0$.

To know if the sign changes, the easiest way to check is based on the [multiplicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicity_(mathematics)#:%7E:text=The%20multiplicity%20of%20a%20root,the%20fundamental%20theorem%20of%20algebra.) of the root (the exponent on the factor). In this case it's 1, and a factor with an odd multiplicity results in a sign change (if it had been even, the sign wouldn't change at that root).

So, the sign has to change at $x=-7$, and we have $(x+7)(x-4) <0$ as we pass through $x=-7$. The next time it can change is at $x=4$, and using the same logic (multiplicity is odd), we know the sign changes again, and we have $(x+7)(x-4)>0$.

So, the product is positive for $x<-7$ or $x>4$. If you graph the quadratic $y=(x+7)(x-4)$, the function is above the $y$-axis for those same two intervals, and it's below on the interval $-7<x<4$.