# does sign of a rational or polynomial equations remains the same for entire interval?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

can a sign of polynomial or rational inequality can be determined by one element within that interval, for the entire interval? when solving inequality we don't take all elements into account, only one element is taken into consideration

suppose we have some inequalities like this $\frac{x-1}{x+3}>0$ and $(x-3)(x+2) \leq 0$

for the first one, we have to check in the domain of $(\infty, -3)\cup(-3, 1)\cup (1, \infty)$, for the second domain is $(\infty, -2]\cup [-2, 3]\cup [3, \infty)$

in the above intervals, we only check for one point - this seems conventional, but can it be said for sure that the sign of polynomial or rational expression remains the same for the entire interval $(a,b)$, what it is for $c$, where $c \in (a,b)$, and how does this differ from different types of intervals, half-closed, fully closed, open ?

Comment: These are products or quotients of expressions of the form $x-a$, whose sign is constant on $(-\infty,a)$ and on $(a,+\infty).$ Then, simply use the sign rules.

Comment: @AnneBauval Well, I could not find any counter-example for my statement, it seems true, I don't know why maybe there will be something in later calculus classes, but I think whatever is the sign at $c$, it will be same for at the entire interval when trying to solve inequality.

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes, for $(-\infty, a)$ it will surely be negative, and $(a, \infty)$ will be positive, as $a$ is the solution i.e $y=0$, and functions are continuous so the change will only occur here, from negative to positive or vice-versa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is continuous on an interval $(a, b)$ and $f(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in (a, b)$, then either $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \in (a, b)$ or $f(x) < 0$ for all $x \in (a, b)$. You can prove this very quickly via contradiction if you apply the Intermediate Value Theorem.

So if we apply this result to the product $f(x)g(x)$, if we have an interval where both functions are (a) continuous and (b) never equal to zero, we have four possibilities:

1. Both functions are always positive, so $f(x)g(x) > 0$ on the whole interval;
2. Both functions are always negative, so $f(x)g(x) > 0$ on the whole interval;
3. $f(x) > 0$ and $g(x) < 0$ for all $x$ on the interval, so $f(x)g(x) < 0$ on the whole interval; or
4. $f(x) < 0$ and $g(x) > 0$ for all $x$ on the interval, so $f(x)g(x) < 0$ on the whole interval.

In other words, the product will always keep the same sign across the whole interval, so if we take any point $c$ in the interval and check the sign of $f(c)g(c)$, we know that that will be the sign of the product on the whole interval.

So conversely, if we want to find the regions in which the product is positive, we know that the only time the sign *could* change is where the functions either cross zero or stop being continuous, and so it is enough to break the domain into sub-intervals where those conditions apply.

Answer (score -1):

For any continuous function (in the real field, at least), the sign can be calculated by sampling a single number within the interval $(-\infty, a)$, $(a, b)$, or $(b, +\infty)$ where $a, b\in f^{-1}(0)$.

In other words, for all $R\to R$ (real number) functions $f$ that satisfy $
\lim_{h\to x}f(h)=f(x)$ (which includes all polynomial and rational functions), the interval strictly between two adjacent solutions, or between negative infinity and the lowest solution, or between the highest solution and infinity, has the same sign all throughout.

The reason for this is that a continuous function cannot have a sudden "jump," meaning that for the sign to change, the function has to pass through zero. However, any point where the function passes through zero is a solution.